# Disable RichTextBox zooming while scrolling with ctrl key

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am using RichTextBox in my c# application, I want to disable RichTextBox zooming while scrolling cursor with ctrl key, How to disable this? Please help.

Comment: Please provide your current research

Answer (score 2):

You could override the [WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx) of a custom `RichTextBox` control and filter the [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) Message. Then re-define the `wParam` content value (this value reports which combination of mouse buttons are pressed at that time), setting it to `0` (`IntPtr.Zero`).

Then, let know that you processed this message, returning a `m.Result` of `0` (`IntPtr.Zero`).
(See the Docs on the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message about this).

To test it, create a new Class and substitute its content with this code (except the `Namespace`). Build the Solution/Project. Find the `RTBNoZoom` control in your ToolBox and drop it on a Form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RTBNoZoom : RichTextBox
{
    private const int MK_CONTROL = 0x0008;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;

    public RTBNoZoom() { }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                if (((int)m.WParam & MK_CONTROL) == MK_CONTROL)
                {
                    m.WParam = IntPtr.Zero;
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Or, if you're not already overriding WndProc, you could override [OnMouseWheel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmousewheel), then cast its `MouseEventArgs` argument to [HandledMouseEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.handledmouseeventargs), setting its **`Handled`** property to `true`.

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0) {
        ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
    }
    else {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: If that works, you can keep your original RTB on the form, derive from [NativeWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow?view=net-5.0), and then assign the handle from your RTB to the NativeWindow using `AssignHandle()`, [similar example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146176/c-sharp-treeview-becomes-missmatched-between-data-and-display/65148207#65148207).

Answer (score 1):

create an eventhandler for richtextbox ContentsResized event. Therein, type

```
private void richTextBox1_ContentsResized(object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.ZoomFactor = 1.0f;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MOUSEWHEEL command and control.modifiers properties to control the zooming of your application.

```
protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
    {               
    // Do what you want here            
    }
    else
    {
    base.DefWndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```